# How to create a WPF custom control in Visual Studion Express edition

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

Did anybody managed to create a WPF custom control in Visual Studion Express edition?

There are no templates available for WPF Custom Control Library on solution level, and not for Custom Control (WPF) on a project level.
Thank you

Comment: eehh... a "custom control" is a class that inherits from `System.Windows.Controls.Control`. Simply create a C# code file and type your code there. Doesn't look like you need a greater level of IDE support for that.

Comment: Yes, It was my first assumption too. I did it, but looks like it is not enough. Not to mention that in order to make System.Windows.Controls.Control available I have to add to standard dll project references to PresentationCore